# JavaScript Function is not working and throwing uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, error-handling, onclick

I have written a javascript function called **offercheck()** and I am calling it with another function on a button on-click event.

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="btn button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this);offerCheck();"><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></button>
```

And the function is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var sku = <?php echo json_encode($skus); ?>;
        function offerCheck() {
               <?php if($sku_hide == 'EBFDAC') { ?>
                 if (jQuery.inArray("Offer", sku) !== -1)
                  {
                  }else
                  {
                   jQuery("#ep-product-sh").modal();
                  }
        <?php } ?>        
        }

    });
</script>
```

But whenever i click on the button i am getting uncaught reference error as below.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: offer_check is not defined

Can anyone kindly tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Define `offerCheck` function in global scope. Move it outside document ready handler

Comment: When using an `on*` event attribute the function needs to be declared under the scope of the window, so move it outside the document.ready handler. Also note that calling `submit` on a form from JS is pretty redundant when you can just change the button to `type="submit"`. Also, don't use inline event handlers, it's not the 90s any more. Use unobtrusive event handlers instead

Comment: @satpal That worked! thanks.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thank you it worked after moving it out of document.ready handler. and noted Will try to use the unobtrusive event handlers. I am Pretty new and noob in javascript, Thank you for the advice.